# How to Mock an object that is not set to a variable

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am currently writing unit tests for legacy code. I need to Mock an object for a "doReturn" on a function call on that object. However, that object is instantiated on the same line it is being called and is never assigned to a variable. Is there a way to mock this return value without touching the original code?

Legacy code line containing function call that needs to return a mocked list:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> referenceDataList = new ReferenceDataInquiryMapper().execute(referenceDataInquiry);
```

My attempt at mocking this "execute" call:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> referenceDataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
//Add data to referenceDataList
ReferenceDataInquiryMapper referenceDataInquiryMapper = PowerMockito.mock(ReferenceDataInquiryMapper.class);
PowerMockito.doReturn(referenceDataList).when(referenceDataInquiryMapper,"execute",Mockito.any());
```

I have also attempted:

```java
PowerMockito.doReturn(referenceDataList).when(new ReferenceDataInquiryMapper(),"execute",Mockito.any());
```

Which throws a PowerMockito error

As well as this:

```java
PowerMockito.doReturn(referenceDataList).when(PowerMockito.mock(ReferenceDataInquiryMapper.class),"execute",Mockito.any());
```

Which throws the same exception as my first attempt.

Instead of returning the Mock value, the first line posted above tries to create an actual new object when the test is ran and throws an exception. Is it possible to actually Mock this code?

~Thanks

Comment: Modify the code to not create the object itself, but have it dependency injected. Can't modify the code? Then there is no point in writing a unit test for it - if you find a bug using the test, you can't modify the code to fix it so writing the test is an exercise in futility

Comment: For clarification, do you mean to say there is no way to mock " = new object().getObject()"? @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: You need to stub the call to `new` to return a mock, and stub the `execute` separately.

Comment: You don't need PowerMockito for this; what you *do* need to do is to pass the `ReferenceDataInquiryMapper` to the class under test as a constructor parameter instead of `new`ing it up. (You can use `this(new RDIM())` if that make things easier to wire.)

Answer (score 0):

when a new object is created, we need to return its mock. Add whenNew as below.

```
List<Map<String, String>> referenceDataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
//Add data to referenceDataList
ReferenceDataInquiryMapper referenceDataInquiryMapper = 
PowerMockito.mock(ReferenceDataInquiryMapper.class);

PowerMockito.whenNew(ReferenceDataInquiryMapper.class).thenReturn( referenceDataInquiryMapper);

PowerMockito.doReturn(referenceDataList).when( referenceDataInquiryMapper,"execute",Mockito.any());
```